# Is it possible to convert .pdf file to image in ionic with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, image, pdf, ionic2

I am very new to ionic. So I want to convert my pdf file to an image file in using Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have rendered the PDF in your appliaction using PDF.JS, converting a PDF page to an image is nothing special. PDF.JS uses a  element to render a PDF (although it can also be set to use an SVG). You can easily convert the underlying canvas to an image using canvas.toDataURL method.
We can use canvaz to pdf convertion for this purpose
For more information : 
http://usefulangle.com/post/24/pdf-to-jpeg-png-with-pdfjs